# Promises not firing using an Listener

Tags: angularjs, promise

I have the following code:

```
app.factory('testservice', function ($rootScope, $q) {
    var defer = $q.defer();
    defer.promise.then(
        function (){alert('Never fires. Resolve');},
        function (){alert('Never fires. Reject');}
    );
    document.addEventListener('event', function () {
        alert("Fires");
        $rootScope.$apply(defer.resolve);
        alert("Fires");}, false);
   });
}
```

It is an angular website. And I was playing with promies. The problem is that the promise is not firing, when I am resolving the promise in an listener...why?

Btw of course here the promise has no sense, but I am only testing...and I am pretty sure I am missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of testing with a factory which won't get invoking unless something else depends on it, just use the module run function. I've fixed several syntax errors in your previous code and everything appears to be working now.

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/JdDRyF?p=preview)

Javascript:

```
angular.module('plunker', [])

.run(function ($rootScope, $q, $log) {
    var defer = $q.defer();
    defer.promise.then(
        function (){$log.log('Resolved');},
        function (){$log.log('Rejected');}
    );
    document.addEventListener('mouseenter', function () {
        $log.log("mouse enter fired");
        $rootScope.$apply(defer.resolve);
   });
});
```